# Generate and read base64 private key to sign the JWT token from java

Tags: java, jwt, private-key

1- Generating a Private Key, from the command line:

> openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 2048

2. from `java`, read it:

   ```
   String privateKey = IOUtils.toString(TestJwtSecurityUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("/private.key"));
   privateKey = privateKey.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
   privateKey = privateKey.replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
   privateKey = privateKey.replaceAll("\\s+","");

   byte[] encodedKey = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary( privateKey );


   PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);

   KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
   PrivateKey pKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec); // fails
   ```

Got exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException:
>   java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException :
>   DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=58, too big.

I tried to convert to base64:

```
byte[] encodedKey = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary( encodedString );
 PrivateKey pKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec); // fails
```

got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:251)
```

Q: how to pass this? To make private key being read so in the end I could sing the JWT token:

```
final JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder().setId("id1")
                ....
                .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, pKey);
```

Comment: Dupes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638604/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934846/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216969/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243018/ . Short answer: use `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt`, or `openssl pkey`. Or generate with `keytool` or JCE in the first place instead of OpenSSL. @michalk: no, `genrsa` does not encrypt, but it uses 'traditional' (PKCS1) format not PKCS8 format.

Comment: So `-aes256` does not encrypt the key content while using `genrsa`?

Comment: Maybe your Java code could use your key easier, if you put it into a .jks or .p12 keystore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is duplicate. But since I spent more than 1 h looking for it in SO site. Based on this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934846/read-rsa-private-key-of-format-pkcs1-in-java), and [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/)'s PEMParser. Thanks, @dave_thompson_085

1. To create a private-public keys:

   - openssl genrsa -out private.key 4096
   - openssl rsa -pubout -in private.key -out public.key
2. then from `java`

--

```
         final PrivateKey pKey = getPrivateKey();

         final SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.RS256; // private key to sign / public to confrim a sign
     final JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder().setId("id1")
                    .setIssuedAt(now)
                    .setSubject(subject)
                    .setIssuer(issuer)
                    .setAudience("api")
                    .addClaims(Map.of(
                            "user_name", "test user",
                            "authorities", List.of("ROLE_USER"),
                            "scope", List.of("read", "write"),
                            "client_id", "test-client"
                            )
                    )                     .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, pKey);
```

---

```
String jwt = builder.compact();
```

where:

```
private static PrivateKey getPrivateKey() throws Exception {

        val path = TestUtils.class.getResource("/").getPath();

        final PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(path + "/private.key"));
        final JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
        final PEMKeyPair object = (PEMKeyPair) pemParser.readObject();
        final KeyPair kp = converter.getKeyPair(object);
        final PrivateKey pKey = kp.getPrivate();

        return pKey;
    }
```

Then to check, paste: generated `jwt` to https://jwt.io/ (or any other tool) to see/check the content.

put a public.key content there to check the signature. To see that all is green.