# What is the encrypted RSA PEM format from OpenSSL `genrsa`?

Tags: openssl, rsa, private-key, pem

I have some encrypted private keys and passphrases that I would like to load into .NET without OpenSSL, but I am having trouble finding the format and specification for them.

I can parse and decode the binary data from PEM, and originally I was thinking I would get PKCS#8, but that seems to not be the case.

The OpenSSL command to create them is such as `openssl genrsa -des3 -out test.key 2048` resulting in a file like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,7EF293A7B0C43A20
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

As far as I can tell, the base64 encoded data is not valid DER/ASN,  tools I found just say the data is invalid, including `openssl asn1parse -inform PEM`.. I assume those two "headers" are the distinguishing feature, but what is the format? What are the common values?

RFC 1421 seems to call such headers "encapsulated header", I didn't find them otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **OpenSSL's 'traditional' or 'legacy'** format private key file (or one of several, depending how you count). It is documented in the man page, on your system or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/PEM_read_PrivateKey.html#PEM-ENCRYPTION-FORMAT), for the related routines -- nominally `man 3 PEM_{read,write}{,_bio}_{RSA,DSA,EC}PrivateKey` although this page is duplicated or symlinked under numerous names -- in the 'PEM ENCRYPTION FORMAT' section. Briefly, the data is encrypted (with a chosen symmetric algorithm, in this example DES3 aka DESede aka triple-DES, with CBC and IV) using a key derived from the password (with salt equal to the IV or part of it, which is unusual, and only one iteration, which is weak). The password-based key derivation function used, `EVP_BytesToKey`, has its own man page.

This is **not PKCS8**. In addition to being encrypted differently than PKCS8-encrypted (formally, `EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo`) the *clear* data that you get after decrypting (or if you don't encrypt to start with, e.g. `genrsa` without `-$cipher`) is not PKCS8-clear `PrivateKeyInfo`. It is instead an algorithm-dependent data format; for RSA it is the format defined in [PKCS1 appendix A.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.2), and for DSA and EC it has other formats not relevant here.

OpenSSL *also* supports PKCS8 privatekey files, both clear and encrypted, which have different PEM types: `BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY` and `BEGIN/END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY` but **not** `BEGIN/END {RSA,DSA,EC} PRIVATE KEY`. For the API see that same man page. You can convert at command line with

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 <tradfile >pk8file [-nocrypt | -v1 pbcipher | -v2 plaincipher]`
# since 1.0.0 in 2010 you can add -iter N
# or since 1.0.0 simply
openssl pkey <tradfile >pk8file [-$cipher]
```

PKCS8 is both more standard (and interchangeable) and more secure, thus recommended -- as that same man page says in the immediately preceding NOTES section.

The *Java* version of [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org) supports OpenSSL PEM formats in `bcpkix`. I don't know for the dotnet version but it might be worth looking.

If not, or if you can't use it, you can convert the (decrypted) PKCS1 format to PKCS8 by adding a mostly-fixed header; in ASN.1 terms, PKCS8 is a wrapper that contains some metadata plus an OCTET STRING containing for RSA the PKCS1 encoding. I don't have a dotnet solution for this but you can probably adapt from Java using my list of links at [Algid parse error, not a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559272/algid-parse-error-not-a-sequence) and perhaps [Converting a string private key to PrivateKey type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55675963/converting-a-string-private-key-to-privatekey-type) .